# How to replace blog page url with subdomain at all places, even in xml sitemap?

Tags: customization, seo, domain-mapping

I've a blog page in wordpress site at http://website.com/blog I want this should be accessed with http://blog.website.com and even the any blog article's link should be http://blog.website.com/article-of-the-week. and search-engine should also take the link as http://blog.website.com/article-of-the-week not http://website.com/blog/article-of-the-week

I'm also using google XML sitemap plugin. and for the blog page url I want to submit the url as http://blog.website.com not http://website.com/blog

As a example site you can take this http://www.ndesign-studio.com/blog it's a site which has blog page.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Subdomains do not contribute to your main site's search engine ranking.

Comment: The example URL you gave has not the setup you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

If the blog can actually be accessed at http://blog.website.com, you'll need to edit your `siteURL` and `home` settings on the Options screen within WordPress.  This will set your blog's default home to be http://blog.website.com instead of http://website.com/blog.

There are more specific instructions [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) ...

Comment: no http://blog.website.com is only for blog page not for main site. this is the sites which has a blog page(section)

Comment: As a example you can take this http://www.ndesign-studio.com/blog

Comment: In that case, I don't think what you want to do can actually be done.